# Image Uploaded to the asp.net web API server in android

Tags: java, android

we are getting problem in image upload through the web API. We try lot many example but it not working and data are not store to database

Comment: Post your code @Kunal Kumar only then ppl can find what went wrong with your code and might be able to help you.

Comment: in which format you are trying to add image? bytearray, multipart, base64 or other? can you specify the question in a bit detail?

Comment: There are dozens ways to achive that show your code!

Comment: @DeepPatel sir it is the multipart format

Comment: @rekire sir we using this example https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/